# mySQL query : involving 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
table 1 : id, name, age, gender.
table 2(friend) : id1,id2. (stored only once i.e only one entry for a unique pair)
```

I need to write a query that takes an id and then return the result set containing the rows from table 1 corresponding to all his/hers friend.

I tried this Query

```
"SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN ("
+ "(SELECT id2 FROM table2 WHERE (id1="+given_id+")) UNION "
+ "(SELECT id1 FROM table2 WHERE (id2="+given_id+")));"
```

but it does'nt seem to work says syntax error ... could anyone help me with this query.

Efforts appreciated ... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar to this.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, WHERE t1.id = t2.id2
```

Comment: Hey sorry I had two typos in my previous question, could you please take a look at edited version ... Thanks a lot +1

Comment: -1 For using implicit join syntax. (Out of votes now). 1989 wants its anti-patterns back.

Comment: There was a relationship table but he updated his question and removed it. Check the history

Comment: Aha, a well the query is incorrect and you left a few syntax errors in. And it really does not match any version of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to single quote `given_id`, because otherwise MySQL will think it is a column name.
This code will also work if `given_id` is a number.

```
"SELECT t1.* "
+"FROM table1 t1 "
+"INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id1 OR t1.id = t2.id2) "
+"WHERE '"+given_id+"' IN (t2.id1, t1.id) "
```

Comment: but given_id is int ... so it should work right... also that sould give error that column name not found right?

Comment: @koool, please don't vote people up `for effort` only vote people up if the answer is actually correct.

Answer (score 1):

Please use a join query:

```
"SELECT `table1`.* FROM (`table1`) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `table2` ON 
        `table1`.`id` = `table2`.`id1`
    WHERE `table2`.`id2` =
    " + given_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can narrow down your results by restricting conditions on a join.  Since you will have to join your table2 on more than one id, you will have to join to it twice and alias the table names.

I believe something like this may do the trick:

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1
JOIN table2 t2 ON table1.id = t2.id2
  AND t2.id1 = {given_id}
JOIN table2 t3 ON table1.id = t3.id1
  AND t3.id2 = {given_id};
```

Comment: `you cannot do nested queries in the where statement in SQL` That's nonsense, you can do nested selects just about anywhere, as long as each subselect _(that's not in an `IN` clause)_ has its own alias.

Comment: You're right.  Don't know what I was thinking.  I will edit the comment to make it less misleading.